# Alternative project management / communication app similar to Basecamp? (Specifically their message board format)

Tags: project-management

I'm a long-time user of Basecamp, most notably Basecamp 3 and now they've started transitioning to Basecamp 4.

I run a busy digital agency in the UK, we have 200+ projects on the go, and the Message Board is 90% of what we use Basecamp for.

The main feature we like with the message board (and the similar To Do format) is that it gives full screen priority to the messages, and doesn't hide them away in a tiny window like other project management apps do.

This allows our agency to communicate very effectively with customers, using rich message content complete with images, video etc - just a really nice visual thread.

We use Asana internally at our agency, which is great for micro-management of tasks & projects, but we don't invite clients to that. Instead it's just an app for our team only to keep track of everything.

So our use of Basecamp is really a messaging tool for our clients, for regular project communication.

However in the last few months, the team at Basecamp have rolled some admittedly crappy updates, almost breaking the notification system as we needed it. The internal problems at Basecamp are well known, so I'm looking around for any possible alternatives.

So what else is out there that has a message board as good as Basecamps? As mentioned above we use Asana internally but want to keep a degree of separation, plus Asana doesn't have a messaging format that we like.

Thinking out loud whilst I type, I suppose we're looking for something more akin to a forum messaging format. We don't require the ability to run and manage the project itself (instead we do that in Asana), instead we just want a way of creating threads and managing messages between our agency and our clients.

Any recommendations / suggestions? (We don't want/need an instant messaging solution).

Answer (score 0):

Not having any experience with Basecamp I took a quick look at the message board feature.

https://3.basecamp-help.com/article/46-message-board

It looks like a simple message board with basic features.

I would suggest to use a software comparison tool to determine:

https://www.g2.com/products/basecamp/competitors/alternatives